Quarto text in visual studio stuck as red
I'm having an issue with Visual Studio Code (VS Code) where the text in my Quarto file appears entirely in red. This problem persists regardless of any changes I make, including switching between different themes in VS Code. I'm unsure why this is happening or how to resolve it. Could someone help me understand why my Quarto text is displaying in red and suggest potential solutions to fix this issue? Any additional details or troubleshooting steps would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!


Hello, I guess this might be an issue after the update. You can choose to downgrade to VS Code 1.91.1 and see if that fix. Or wait for a fix.

I think this is due to the VS code update. The last published update of the quarto vs code extension was 1.113.0 (Release on 30 May 2024), but a new version of VS code (1.92.0) came out today. Does it count as  a "bug" for either the quarto extension or VS code, I wonder?
UPDATE: it counts as a bug in the VS code extension, but the workaround for now is to downgrade VS code until the new extension is released.
